# Computer in General

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, desktop, display-settings

Just recently bought a new desktop.  It is a PowerSpec. Bought two monitors with it; they are Acer 27inch-both exactly the same monitor.

I can see a difference in the background one looks sharp(darker) and the other one looks dull(lighter). The color of the background is just black. The one that is dull looking is connected via HDMI cord, and the sharper looking one is DVI Cord.  I switched Cords on the Monitors to be sure it wasn't a monitor having issue, when I switched the cords the color did switch screens.  So do I need to set up one monitor differently on the color variation or what?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. Since HDMI was introduced as a standard to connect multimedia devices and TVs, some Monitors will use colors and even do post processing on those signals, possibly making the TV experience better but runining your desktop picture. Look for a setting in the Screen that says TV mode, game mode. Ultimately this seems to be a problem of limited color http://referencehometheater.com/2014/commentary/rgb-full-vs-limited/

Comment: I will read into this more with the link provided. THANK YOU for responding, it is driving me nuts. You can't use two of the same cords to have multiple monitors !!!